# Como actualizar un proyecto realizado en Netbeans 8.2 con JAVA JSF 2.2 y Primefaces 5.0, si se añaden dos campos a una tabla de la Base de Datos

Tags: base-de-datos, jsf, primefaces, netbeans-8.2

Saludos  por favor si me pueden ayudar con este problema.

El problema radica en que ya avance con varios cambios sobre el proyecto y no me gustaría crear un nuevo proyecto para nada mas de aumentar 2 campos en la tabla, En mi proyecto use las clases "Clases entidad a partir de la base de datos" y luego la "JSF pages from entity classes", como muestra la imagen:

[image: Cases usadas en el proyecto]

Y todo funciona bien, pero en la tabla de nombre "OrdenTrabajo" aumentaron 2 nuevas columnas y con el valor del ultimo quiero hacer un semáforo para alertar al usuario, pero eso es otra cosa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como actualizo para que me aparezcan las nuevas columnas sin que se dañe el css ni pe property del programa, que ya lo intente sobrescribiendo pero se me daña el proyecto.

Tal vez a alguien ya le paso. 
Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, si has usado el mismo IDE para generar las Entidades, seguramente debes tener una clase por cada tabla.

Revisa la clase que este relacionada con la tabla, y luego en esa clase, añade los 2 campos que tambien le añadiste a la tabla, con sus anotaciones o sus configuraciones si son XML.

Luego, para tu Datatable en pantalla, agrega las nuevas columnas, y en cada una especifica las nuevas propiedades que le agregaste a tu clase y tambien a tu tabla.

Saludos